# Write trigger file once all files have been moved to unix

Tags: java

I would like to move all the files to unix and once all the files have been moved, write a trigger file to unix.
Below is the code:-

```
  public static void download(CloudFileDirectory root, 
  CloudFileDirectory backup) throws StorageException, URISyntaxException, 
  FileNotFoundException {

    ResultSegment<ListFileItem> list = 
  root.listFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented();
    for (ListFileItem item : list.getResults()) {
        URI uri = item.getUri();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String localPath = localRootDirPath;
        String itemName = new File(path).getName();

            CloudFile file = root.getFileReference(itemName);
            file.download(new FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+itemName));
            CloudFile backupFile = backup.getFileReference(itemName);
            backupFile.startCopy(file);
            file.delete();

            file.download(new 
     FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+"ok_business"));
        }
     }
```

Problem above is that, it creates a trigger file 'ok_business' after the first file is move to unix but I want to create only once all the files have been moved.

Comment: Then you shouldn't do it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move call

```
file.download(new 
     FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+"ok_business"));
```

out of your for-loop.

You are calling it in the loop, and after the first iteration it is being created as you have described.

Instead of code:

```
for (ListFileItem item : list.getResults()) {
        URI uri = item.getUri();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String localPath = localRootDirPath;
        String itemName = new File(path).getName();

            CloudFile file = root.getFileReference(itemName);
            file.download(new FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+itemName));
            CloudFile backupFile = backup.getFileReference(itemName);
            backupFile.startCopy(file);
            file.delete();

            file.download(new 
     FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+"ok_business"));
 }
```

Use this approach. Move `CloudFile file` file declaration outside of the `for-loop`. And move the last expression outside from the `for-loop`.

```
CloudFile file;
for (ListFileItem item : list.getResults()) {
        URI uri = item.getUri();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String localPath = localRootDirPath;
        String itemName = new File(path).getName();

            file = root.getFileReference(itemName);
            file.download(new FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+itemName));
            CloudFile backupFile = backup.getFileReference(itemName);
            backupFile.startCopy(file);
            file.delete();
 }

   // preventing Null Pointer Exception for cases, when file is not initialized
   if (file!=null) {
       file.download(new FileOutputStream(localRootDirPath+"ok_business"));
   }
```

Comment: Doing so, he won't have reference to `file` object.

Comment: @Sahilkhan Glad, I helped you :)

Comment: Hi @Rafael, 
I am stuck at one more issue.
"Extract all the recurring element of XML using java"
Could you please help me if possible.

Comment: @Sahilkhan For separate issue please make a separate question post on StackOverflow. And check these links: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html   and  https://mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/

Comment: @Rafael, yes, question has been posted 10 days back. :)

Comment: @Sahilkhan I have posted the answer to that question. Please check.